# Toggling table row changes width of columns in other rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, toggle

I have a table like the following:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr class="clickme">
    <td width="1%">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td width="50px">C</td>
    <td width="50px">D</td>
</tr>

<tr class="contain">
    <td colspan="4">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the following js

```
$(function(){
    $('.clickme').click(function(){
        $(this).next('tr').toggle();
     });
});
```

For Opera this is fine, however, in IE and Firefox, when I toggle the `.contain` table row, all of the `.clickme` table row's columns' width changes, anyone has any idea why?

Comment: What browser and platform? I can't see the effects you describe in this [JS Fiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NZqFS/). (The `background-color` doesn't make a difference, it was just so's I could clearly see what row I was on.) Tested on Ubuntu 11.04, with Firefox 4, Chromium 11 and Opera 11.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in FF4 and IE8.

Comment: Can you make your table width a fixed value and try?

Comment: It's working fine for me on FF 4.0. Check with jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zCAnk/)

Comment: working fine: see http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/gRSAV/   where is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
$(this).siblings().toggle();
```